# Фаервол в Ubuntu

Tags: firewall, ubuntu

Как отключить Фаервол в Ubuntu 10?

Comment: Не знал что такой вообще существует :))

Comment: @metazet Для комментариев правильно использовать комментарии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo ufw disable

Answer (score 3):

В вопросе не сказано, какой именно фаервол использован.
предполагаю, что имеется ввиду остановка iptables.
    iptables -FZ
Правда перед этим рекомендую всетаки сохранить текущие установки
    iptables-save >iptables.rules
Вдруг еще пригодятся